# 403 Error with Access Not Configured. Google Calendar API w/ JS

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to make a google-chrome extension that will add items into Google Calendar. I am trying to use their API but am running into this error:

code: 403, message: "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."

I have spent quite a bit of time trying to figure out if anything was not enabled, but to no avail. I have enabled both CalDAV API and Calendar API and I am using the Client ID for installed applications (Chrome App) as well as the Simple API Access.

Here is my code:

```
var clientId = 'XXXXXXXX6189-2f8rbvs2ppnek5eo3h9e9dshXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var apiKey = 'AIzXXXXXXXX38BVIsgWX3orqxqbSmoyh3nKa89w';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);

/* ... */

gapi.client.load("calendar", "v3", function(){
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list({});
    request.execute(function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/):

> Activating an API associates that API with the current project and
>   adds monitoring pages for that API, enables billing for that API, and
>   adds any custom information to the Developers Console for that API.

Hence I think that you have to enable billing for the project in-order to access them.

Answer (score 0):

I only know It in PHP, + I wouldn't recommend showing your Client ID and API key online, replace with XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com & AIzaSyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.

I'm guessing that's not your full code...

1. Have you included the google api library?
2. Has the library got sufficient permissions
3. should add your calendar ID
4. have you written some html to contain and display the calendar list? or are you just checking the json feed?
5. good luck